# NSTableColumn width computation doesn't work correctly on macOS 11

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm manually calculating the minimum size of my `NSTableColumn` to avoid text ellipsization. The calculation looks like this:

```
NSCell *cell = [m_view preparedCellAtColumn:m_column row:row];

int width = ceil([cell cellSize].width);

if(m_column == [m_view outlineTableColumn]) {
   width += [m_view indentationPerLevel] * [m_view levelForRow:row];
   width += m_expander;
}
```

The `m_expander` value is calculated like this:

```
// assume that row 0 has an expander
NSRect rc = [m_view frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:0];
m_expander = ceil(rc.origin.x + rc.size.width);
```

This works nicely on 10.13. See this screenshot:

[image: macOS 10.13]

On macOS 11, however, the calculation is not correct and the text gets ellipsized:

[image: macOS 11]

Debugging has shown that `m_expander` is missing 4 pixels on macOS 11. On macOS 10.13 `rc.origin.x` is 6 and `rc.size.width` is 12. On macOS 11, `rc.origin.x` is 2 and `rc.size.width` is 12. However, this seems to be correct because you can see that the space to the left of the expander is smaller on macOS 11 than on macOS 10.13 so the values look correct. All other values are identical between 10.13 and 11. The column width computed by 10.13 is 169 and the column width computed by macOS 11 is 165.

Still, as you can see, the overall column width calculation is not correct on macOS 11 because the text gets ellipsized. Anybody got an idea what the problem here is?

Comment: The cell based table/outline view is deprecated and is getting buggy. Have you tried adding `cell.cellSize.width - [m_view frameOfCellAtColumn:m_column row:row].size.width` to the current column width?

Comment: Yes, but then it doesn't work on 10.13 anymore. On 10.13 this yields -2.073242 whereas on 11 it is 3.882324. Those 4 pixels are enough to make ellipsation go away on 11 but on 10.13 it's negative :(

Comment: Would it be enough to always add 4 pixels as some sort of workaround?

Comment: I don't have macOS 11 but it works for me on 10.13. What are the values of `cell.cellSize.width`, `[m_view frameOfCellAtColumn:m_column row:row].size.width` and `m_view.tableColumns[m_column].width` on macOS 10.13 and 11?

Comment: On 10.13 they are 134.926758, 137, 169 and on 11 they are 134.882324, 131, 165.

Comment: Is the column width on 10.13 too small and is the text truncated?

Comment: No, on 10.13 everything is working correctly. On 11 the column width is 4 pixels too small. If I always add 4 on macOS 11, everything is fine.

Comment: I thought you solved the issue but then I noticed the question on the mailing list. Is the negative value -2.073242 on 10.13 a problem? The column is a bit too wide.

Answer (score 0):

The cell based `NSTabelView` is deprecated, isn't maintained very well and is getting buggy.

> Anybody got an idea what the problem here is?

Lets check the frames and sizes on macOS 10.13:

```
m_view.tableColumns[0].width: 116

[m_view frameOfCellAtColumn:0 row:0]: (origin = (x = 17, y = 1), size = (width = 100, height = 17))
[m_view frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:0]: (origin = (x = 6, y = 1), size = (width = 12, height = 16))
[m_view preparedCellAtColumn:column row:0].cellSize: (width = 61.662109375, height = 17)

[m_view frameOfCellAtColumn:0 row:1]: (origin = (x = 33, y = 20), size = (width = 84, height = 17))
[m_view frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:1]: (x = 22, y = 20), size = (width = 12, height = 16))
[m_view preparedCellAtColumn:column row:1].cellSize:  (width = 66.83544921875, height = 17)

[m_view frameOfCellAtColumn:0 row:2]: (x = 49, y = 39), size = (width = 68, height = 17))
[m_view frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:2]: (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))
[m_view preparedCellAtColumn:column row:2].cellSize:  (width = 108.9267578125, height = 17)

[m_view indentationPerLevel]: 16
```

The calculations:

```
NSRect rc = [m_view frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:0];
m_expander = ceil(rc.origin.x + rc.size.width);

m_expander: 18

NSCell *cell = [m_view preparedCellAtColumn:m_column row:row];
int width = ceil([cell cellSize].width);
width += [m_view indentationPerLevel] * [m_view levelForRow:row];
width += m_expander;

row 0, width = 80
row 1, width = 101
row 2, width = 159
```

But the minimal column width where the text isn't truncated is 157. The cell at row 0 starts at x = 17 instead of 18. Apparently the spacing between the cells isn't 0.

Solution:

Add the difference between the current size of the cell and the minimum size of the cell to the current size of the column.

```
CGFloat widthToAdd = -CGFLOAT_MAX;
for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < m_view.numberOfRows; row++) {
    CGFloat requiredCellWidth = [m_view preparedCellAtColumn:m_column row:row].cellSize.width;
    CGFloat currentCellWidth = [m_view frameOfCellAtColumn:m_column row:row].size.width;
    CGFloat delta = requiredCellWidth - currentCellWidth;
    if (delta > widthToAdd)
        widthToAdd = delta;
}
NSTableColumn *column = m_view.tableColumns[m_column];
CGFloat newMinWidth = column.width + ceil(widthToAdd);
if (column.width < newMinWidth)
    column.width = newMinWidth; // set width before minWidth, setting minWidth first doesn't update the column
column.minWidth = newMinWidth;
```